# I want to append 1st element of numpy array with 1st element in another numpy array and do this for all other elements

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy, append

I have Three numpy arrays

```
X = [1,2,3,4,4,5,56,..,n]
Y = [1,2,344,4,4,4,..,n]
Z = [1,2,244,24,445,64,..,n]
```

I want to make output like this

`final_list = [(X1,Y1,Z1),(X2,Y2,Z2),(X3,Y3,Z3), ... (Xn,Yn,Zn)]`

And then to check if Z in any of them is > some threshold
Pop it up all with its correspondence X and Y

Is there some suggestions please?
I tried
`np.conctatenate`
but no any good results.

Thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way with if else could be:

```
X = [1,2,3,4,4,5,56]
Y = [1,2,344,4,4,4,89]
Z = [1,2,244,24,445,64,89]
d=[]
for i in range(len(X)):
    if Z[i]>thresh:
        print("print something")
    else:
        d.append([X[i],Y[i],Z[i]])
print(d)
```

if you check if `z>thresh` at the time of creating the list there is no need of poping those items later.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jadhav it worked quite well. And is there way then to return them back becuase I want to visualize them in 3D and it is better to have them like all points of x and y and z as i am using the method 

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
ax.scatter(Xs, Ys, Zs, c = 'r', marker = "o")
plt.show()

Answer (score 0):

One way with just list comprehension:

```
out = [(x,y,z) for x,y,z in zip(X,Y,Z) if z<threshold]
```

With numpy you can do something like this:

```
xyz = np.array([X,Y,Z])

under_thresh = xyz[xyz[-1]<threshold]
```